# I have no idea "How change font for elements in widget?"

Tags: plugins, customization, widgets, fonts

I tried to use wp google font plugin to change font for my website. But I cannot change the text of widget. Like image attached, I cannot find the class of the text "เราคือ Nutraallen ผู้จำหน่ายผลิตภัณฑ์เพื่อสุขภาพ อุดมด้วยสารอาหารเข้มข้น เพื่อให้ร่างกายแข็งแรง เสริมสร้างภูมิต้านทาน ด้วยธัญพืชและวัตถุดิบจากธรรมชาติ 100% สำหรับผู้ใส่ใจในสุขภาพ" which I want to change text by wp google font plugin.

When I use the class "widget-title", it changes the word "About Us". But the Thai text above not be changed.

Anyone have the solutions for me? Please help.
[image: Find class of the text]

Answer (score 1):

You're just using the wrong CSS selector. Your p tag is inside a div that has textwidget class. So to do it you need to target that class like this :

```
.textwidget p{
  font-family: sans-serif /* replace 'sans-serif' with your font */
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked. You're welcome :)